# Problem about bijective function

Tags: real-analysis

which of the following statement is True ?

$1.$ There exist a  bijective  function from $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$   to $\mathbb{R}$

$2$ There exist a  bijective function from $\mathbb{Q} $ to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}$

$3$ There does  exists strictly increasing  function from $\mathbb{Z}$  to $\mathbb{N}$

$4$.There does  exists strictly increasing  onto function from $\mathbb{Z}$  to $\mathbb{N}$

I thinks only option $2 $ is true because  countable map to countable

Comment: Statement 1 is also true.

Comment: $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ is *uncountable*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) is true since $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ has same cardinality as $\mathbb R$

2) is true.

3) and 4) are false. Suppose there is a strictly incerasing function $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$. Let $f(0)=n$. Then $f(-1), f(-2),....$ satisfy the inequalities $... f(-n)<f(-n+1)<...<f(-1) <n$. But there are only a finite number of integers less than $n$ in $\mathbb N$. Hence such an $f$ cannot exist.

Comment: ..@KAvi rama if u r assuming $f(0) = n $ then $f(1) = ??$

Comment: You can only say $f(1)$ is some integer greater than $n$.